# Callback for user's responses in a telegram bot (Telegraf)

Tags: node.js, callback, bots, telegram, telegraf

I'm coding a telegram bot with Telegraf on node.js and I need to get some information about users. For example, the bot is asking them where they are from. Then, I want to wait for the user's response and store it in my db. However, I don't understand how to achieve that since I can't just use a `bot.on('text', ...)` because I'm asking multiple questions and need to differenciate responses afterwards. I found out that there are callbacks but all that I found is for buttons and keyboards. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I found the solution, you need to use scenes to achieve that

https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/705